# remix.run meta, getting info from parent routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I have a nested route in Remix that I want to have *mostly the same meta information as its parent. I would assume that if no `meta` property is exported from the route, then Remix would go up the chain until it gets to the root.

This does not appear to be the case, however. I have inspected the args available to the `meta` call and while there is `parentsData` - this is just the data from parent `loader` functions, not parent `meta`.

Ideally, I'd like to have for my root route's meta something like the following

```
export const meta: MetaFunction = (): HtmlMetaDescriptor => ({
  title: 'My App',
});
```

and in nested routes be able to do something like the following:

```
export const meta: MetaFunction = (args): HtmlMetaDescriptor => ({
  title: `${args.parentsData.title} | My Route`,
})
```

Is there something that I'm missing, or some convention that would allow me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Remix does not provide the actual `meta` response from parent to child routes. If you need customized meta values, then you should return those from the loaders directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `parentsData` from all the parent loaders, adding any meta info in there, not direct solution but a work around.

docs:
https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions

Answer (score 0):

**With Remix v2**

You can definitely consume `loader` and `meta` exported from any parent route in the same hierarchy in any nested child route.

Using `matches` paramter as shown below, you can get all your parent data:

```js
export const meta: MetaFunction = ({ matches }) => {
  // this matches array have all the things that all your parents routes export
  console.log(matches);
};
```

In my case output was:

```js
[
  {
    id: 'root',
    data: null,
    meta: [],
    params: { id: '6603feabeaf855326279ab28' },
    pathname: '/',
    handle: undefined,
    error: null
  },
  {
    id: 'routes/desk',
    data: { userId: '652675dc7ad78fd3746a7f73' },
    meta: [],
    params: { id: '6603feabeaf855326279ab28' },
    pathname: '/desk',
    handle: undefined,
    error: null
  },
  {
    id: 'routes/desk.bilties',
    data: { bilties: [Array] },
    meta: [],
    params: { id: '6603feabeaf855326279ab28' },
    pathname: '/desk/bilties',
    handle: undefined,
    error: null
  },
  {
    id: 'routes/desk.bilties.$id',
    data: { bilty: [Object] },
    meta: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    params: { id: '6603feabeaf855326279ab28' },
    pathname: '/desk/bilties/6603feabeaf855326279ab28',
    handle: undefined,
    error: null
  },
  {
    id: 'routes/desk.bilties.$id._index',
    data: null,
    meta: [],
    params: { id: '6603feabeaf855326279ab28' },
    pathname: '/desk/bilties/6603feabeaf855326279ab28/',
    handle: undefined,
    error: null
  }
]
```

From the docs (https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/meta#matches):

> This is an array of the current route matches. You have access to many
> things, particularly the meta from the parent matches and data.

Now your requirement can be satisfied using parent meta merged and exported from child meta function. This can be done in 2 ways:

1. consuming parent data and exporting child route's meta function
2. filter matches data and merge with child route's meta function export
   Note: in any case you need to export the new meta array from child route

You should follow the docs. They have also a gist with helper function to automatically mere parent meta:

1. https://remix.run/docs/en/main/start/v2#route-meta (meta function signature changed in v2 from object to array)
2. https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/meta#merging-with-parent-meta
3. https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/meta#meta-merging-helper